# Equivalent SQL lite Query in ObjectBox

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, objectbox

I have the following SQLlite query, that is supposed to display the Barcode and Sum the Quantity of the barcodes between a specific date range. The SQLite query is shown below:

```
 public Cursor getResult(Date start, Date end) 

    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(start.getTime()), String.valueOf(end.getTime())};
    String selection = "SELECT " + SalesProjections.BARCODE.getName() +
            ", SUM(" + SalesProjections.QUANTITY.getName() + ") " +
            "FROM " + SalesProjections.TABLE_NAME +
            " WHERE " + SalesProjections.DATEPROJECTED.getName() + " BETWEEN ? AND ? " +
            " GROUP BY " + SalesProjections.BARCODE.getName();

    return   RepositoryAPI.getInstance().getCursorByRawQuery(
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            ORDER.ASC,
            SalesProjections.BARCODE.getName());
}
```

I am now trying to convert the same query to use ObjectBox. See the data class and function that follow:

The **SalesProjections** class is as follows :

```
@Entity
data class SalesProjections(
    @Id var id: Long = 0,
    val barCode: String? = null,
    val dateProjected: Long = 0,
    val quantity: Int = 0)
```

and my current attempt at the conversion is as follows:

```
fun getResult(start: Date, end: Date) {

    val builder = saleprojectionBox.query()
    var result = builder
        .between(SalesProjections_.dateProjected, start.time, end.time)
        .order(SalesProjections_.barCode)
        .build()
        .find()
}
```

I know that ObjectBox does not have a GroupBy feature and I did not want to break each result down and get the List or barcodes first and then get the list of quantities based on the barcodes. Can I get a some pointers onto how I can achieve my needs

Comment: Let's do some brainstorming on how an API could look like:

Map<String, List<SalesProjections>> projectionsByBarCode = query.findMappedBy(SalesProjections_.barCode);

Would that help with the first step?